# Handling 2FA Authentication in a Mixed Security Environment

Tags: authentication, security, web

I'm facing a challenge with implementing two-factor authentication (2FA) in a system where some users have 2FA enabled and others do not. The issue arises in determining whether a particular user requires 2FA before the actual authentication process. It seems inappropriate to send a pre-authentication request to check for 2FA necessity, as this could potentially expose sensitive information to unauthorized users.

Here's my current approach:

The user enters their username and password on the frontend.
The server validates these credentials. If 2FA is required, the server sends an HTTP exception indicating the need for 2FA.
The client receives this response and redirects the user to a 2FA code input page.

Question: How should the user complete the authentication process without the server retaining previously entered credentials?
One idea is to use an intermediate token, which grants no resource access but simply confirms that the first stage of authentication is complete. However, I'm concerned about the security implications of this approach.

I'd appreciate your insights on this matter. Which approach do you find more preferable, or is there a better solution that I haven't considered?